# Did Jesus Christ certify that the Apostles were infallible?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, words-of-jesus, apostles, papal-infallibility

As the question asks, which verses in the Bible show that Jesus Christ consecrated the disciples as apostles during his lifetime. Also are there any verses(with words of Jesus in his lifetime) which talk in general about their infallibility. Please support your answer with **authentic** references.

And the definition of authentic according to me is ...

Authentic -   If a source is authentic, then it is proved that it is not fake or fabricated over time by the people passing it, but in fact it was in its true form real and original.

**Update:**
As suggested below I would like to ask the same question this way, if this is what the community prefers...

**What biblical evidence, does the Church use to support the claim, of the papal infallibility in the Catholic Church, and under what grounds does it claim infallibility and it’s ability to teach without error?**

Comment: What do you consider an "authentic" reference? What evidence would suffice for a "no" answer? Because the answer is no.

Comment: A reference which says "Jesus said they'll be right always" and this must be from authentic sources. @curiousdannii

Comment: You didn't answer anything I just asked. What do you mean by "authentic"?

Comment: authentic - **If a source is authentic, then it is proved that it is not fake or fabricated over time by the people passing it by, but in fact it was in its true form real and original.** @curiousdannii :)

Comment: Your question seems more like an introduction to an argument than a search for an answer.  What exactly is it that don't yet know and are trying to learn?

Comment: @servantofWiser Your question title and body are now asking too rather different things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the biblical basis for the doctrine of Papal Infallibility taught by the Catholic Church?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4491/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-the-doctrine-of-papal-infallibility-taught-by-the)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The words used in this question, for example, “Errorless”, or by using open statements solely without proper parameters like “infallibility” without setting up boundaries makes the question easy to answer.   No, Jesus never stated or certified that the apostles where errorless (In all Things) or infallible (In all things), ever.

I may be wrong but I feel this question is directed more to the Catholic Church than Christianity in General.  Someone looking to confirm how the Church is unbiblical and teaching falsely, this has been my experience at any rate. It is often a stone that some stumble over when viewing The Church.   In order to understand these things a proper understanding of what the Church claims, as infallibility would be needed.

I would suggest rewording the original question to:

“What biblical evidence, does the Church use to support the claim, of The Papal Office in the Roman Catholic Church, and under what grounds does it claim infallibility and its inability to teach error?”

I am not sure if I met the rules with my response.  I am new here and this is my first post.

Comment: This might be considered more a comment on the question; it doesn't particularly answer the question (except briefly in the last sentence of the first paragraph). Still, it's a valuable contribution. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site. We're glad you're here. It's not your fault that your answer is a bit off (more like a comment). The question has problems and will probably be put on hold. Please continue to participate and I'm sure you'll pick up the guidlines in short order. Start with the [tour] and [help] then try [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808).

Comment: @fredsbend Thanks for putting in what I overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in the New Testament does it say that Jesus gave any kind of "certificate".  He consecrated the Twelve as apostles, which vested in them certain powers. For example, Peter was given the power to "bind" (seal) on earth and to have that binding valid in heaven; likewise to "loose". He did not tell them they were infallible. These apostles knew they had been ordained by the Son of God; they probably did not feel the need for a piece of paper to prove that.

Later, when apostles sent *others* as emissaries, the apostle would send a letter to explain that that emissary was sent by authority of an apostle  (as when Paul sent Timothy and Epaphroditus to Philippi, mentioned in Philippians 2). You could view such letters as a kind of certificate if you like.

It's not clear to me what you seek. If you believe the Apostles had divine authority, the existence or non-existence of some kind of "authentic certificate" would not change your view; and if you do not believe they had divine authority, even an authentic certificate might not convince you.

As for infallibility, I don't know of any Apostle claiming infallibility; as far as I know, that concept came into being in the Roman Catholic Church, after all the Apostles had been killed.

Comment: I was not literal though. :)

Comment: And to be clear, neither the ordination by Jesus nor the letter of certification from the Apostle guaranteed that the bearer was perfect.

Comment: In fact, Paul makes claims that the disciples of other apostles are teaching incorrect doctrine.

Comment: edited the question plz check ....

Comment: The notion of infallibility is implied by verses such as [Mark 13:11](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Mar&c=13&v=11&t=KJV#s=t_conc_970011). Note how it's not the apostle that speaks, but the Holy Spirit who speaks through the apostle. And, orthodox Christians believe that the Holy Spirit is God, the third person of the Holy Trinity, and therefore, the apostle, while under the inspiration of the Holy Spirit speaking through the apostle at that time, is infallible.

Comment: Consider someone like King David. By himself, he was a sinner who committed adultery. However, he was also a prophet. Now, if we consider King David by himself, someone might say, "How could you believe David's prophecy was accurate, if it came from someone who committed adultery and transgressed God's law?" But, of course, when David prophesied, it was the Holy Spirit speaking in him (cp. [Matt. 22:43](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Mat&c=22&v=43&t=KJV#s=t_conc_951043)); therefore, everything King David prophesied is absolutely true. Under the inspir. of the HS, he was infallible.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 Good addition to the answer, and totally inline with what is being said, in my opinion. Note that there are a few instances where the apostles are corrected by divine revelation, for example