# Is breaking copyright law a sin?

Tags: sin, civil-government, copyright

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are Christians bound to the laws of their country?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2259/are-christians-bound-to-the-laws-of-their-country)

- Making illegal copies of films, music, books and games
- Downloading and seeding torrents
- Using someone else's program code without license
- Plagiarism (which is like breaking 9th Commandment)

Are the things listed above sinful?

Does it depend on whether we're making money from it?

Comment: See also: [How should a christian evaluate whether a particular action a sin or not?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1011/60)

Comment: @Caleb, I don't agree, it's not a duplicate, since there may be other answers, which will move question from proposed subset.

Comment: @MaxGontar: If there are things outside of the subset they should be asked in separate questions and demonstrate how they are not a subset rather than posing the general group like the title of this one suggests. Also remember that most [is X a sin](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/245/30) questions are [considered off topic](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/245/are-is-x-a-sin-questions-on-topic/250#250). By generalizing this into a category I was trying to rescue the topic from simply being closed as off topic.

Comment: I've always thought if you have to ask if something is stealing, you already know the answer is yes.

Comment: @iterationx, that's fine, making mistakes is in human nature.

Comment: [Another title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43810/how-to-appropriately-suggest-title-changes): Is software piracy a sin?

Comment: YES. it's called STEALING.

Comment: @DantheMan my friend, it's not a stealing, can you make a difference of stealing a car, money, wife etc and _stealing_ a song, game, film? Stealing isn't a right term, as for me. It's rather _releasing_ content from a poor greedy mind it was produced by :)

Comment: @MaxGontar: Old question, I know, just wanted to point out that under all traditional and a lot of modern definitions of stealing, piracy does fall under it. Just because someone's greedy, rich or whatever does in no way make it righteous to steal from them.

Comment: The real question is: Is copyright law a just law or even a law at all? Since it's unclear, the Catholic moral principle "*lex dubia non obligat*" ("a doubtful law does not oblige") applies.

Comment: @DanielPendergast U.S. Copyright Law does not classify copyright infringement as theft. Besides, theft is depriving someone of his property, and one is not deprived of his property when information is copied. See [my answer here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/30095/1787), esp. the link to N. Stephan Kinsella's [*Against Intellectual Property*](https://mises.org/library/against-intellectual-property-0) ([free audiobook](https://mises.org/library/against-intellectual-property-4)).

Comment: [Another title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43810/how-to-appropriately-suggest-title-changes)/question: "Is copyright law just?"

Answer (score 5):

This issue is really just a sub-set of a much larger issue. See my answer on [Are Christians bound to the laws of their country?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2259/are-christians-bound-to-the-laws-of-their-country/2261#2261) for a defense of why Christians are bound to follow the laws of their countries whether or not they agree or disagree with them.

Whether or not some of the items you list would or would not fall under a biblical definition of "theft" and thus run afoul of one of the ten commandments, breaking a civil law is still something we're instructed against according to [Romans 13:1](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Romans%2013:1). Hence breaking civil laws and ethical standards is also [disobedience to God, which is sin](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/160/30).

Comment: I think that although from your point of view this question is just a subset of the other question, still there may be other answers. However thank you for your answer, it worth pondering.

Comment: *Lex dubia non obligat.* (A doubtful law does not bind.) is also another moral principle that comes into play here.