# To what duties do author's rights ( ) correlate?

Tags: catholicism, morality, copyright, moral-theology

McHugh & Callan, O.P., [*Moral Theology*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5547) says

> 292. […] rights and duties are correlative—there being a duty that corresponds to every right, and vice versa

To what duties do [author's rights (*ius auctoris*)](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/30095/1787) correlate?

Comment: Down-voter, please explain your down-vote.

Comment: I upvoted to reverse :-).