# is piracy always a sin no matter what you download?

Tags: ethics

is piracy always a sin ?

i have games from old consoles and emulators of arcade and console many of these games are not

avaliable anymore but on internet so if i download music games programs am i sinning ?

is sharing content a piracy act and a sin against God ?

i know we must obey the law but depending on the country is not ilegal

(i.e in spain is not illegal downloading )

Comment: Hola Jose, generally speaking "is SOMETHING a sin?" questions are off topic here unless you can put a faith tradition behind it, we try not to pose questions that necessarily require us to either self-interpret the Bible or you ask, "according to the Catholic/Anglican/Baptist etc... Church is Piracy a sin" (note, the Catholic question has already been asked) https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/26481/roman-catholic-is-piracy-of-information-and-media-wrong-in-all-circumstances and there is also http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2255/is-breaking-copyright-law-a-sin

Comment: Search the question on copyright law here

Comment: I honestly think that copyright laws are made up and that internet "piracy" is not generally sinful, especially when the creators of the thing being "pirated" have already received due compensation from its sale. However, there may be cases in which piracy is sinful, especially if done maliciously, or because of an unwillingness to pay the creators what is due for their labor. In your case, it doesn't seem you could pay the creators, and they likely have already received just compensation, anyway.